# How to redirect to another route without re-running parent route guards?

Tags: angular

I have following route configuration:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'main',
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [MainGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'child-1',
        component: Child1Component,
        canActivate: [Child1Guard],
      },
      {
        path: 'child-2',
        component: Child2Component,
      },
    ],
  },
])
```

`main` route has `MainGuard`, and it has 2 child routes (`child-1` and `child-2`).

`child-1` route has `Child1Guard`, that just redirects to `child-2`.

What happens is when I open `/main/child-1` in browser, first MainGuard runs, then Child1Guard, and then MainGuard again. And I don't want that.

I want to use MainGuard for fetching some data that is required for all child routes, and `child-1` is just the default route that is never rendered, just there to redirect to another child route.

Note: If I navigate to just '/main' route and after that to 'child-1', `MainGuard` won't run again.

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-v13-2-fhoeyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

> Move the API call to the can activate child, which will ensure, that the validation happens once!

Can activate child might be the solution to your problem:

When I use it, below is the execution sequence!

[image]

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-v13-2-xk3feg)

routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MainGuard } from './main.guard';
import { Child1Component } from './child-1.component';
import { Child1Guard } from './child-1.guard';
import { Child2Component } from './child-2.component';
import { MainResolver } from './main.resolver';
import { ChildResolver } from './child1.resolver';
import { CanActivateTeam } from './main-child.guard';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'main',
        component: MainComponent,
        canActivate: [MainGuard],
        resolve: { test: MainResolver },
        canActivateChild: [CanActivateTeam],
        children: [
          {
            path: 'child-1',
            component: Child1Component,
            canActivate: [Child1Guard],
            resolve: { test: ChildResolver },
          },
          {
            path: 'child-2',
            component: Child2Component,
          },
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'child-1',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: 'main',
      },
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, MainComponent, Child1Component, Child2Component],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

---

This line is the problem!

> I want to use MainGuard for fetching some data that is required for
> all child routes

You need to use a resolver for fetching data needed before the component renders, if you use a resolver your issue will resolve I guess, guards are for authorization and for blocking the component from being rendered when some conditions need to be met, before access can be granted.

Comment: The problem is that Guards are always run before Resolvers, even child route Guards are run before parent route Resolvers. And some of child guards depend on this data. That's why I cannot use resolver

Comment: @displayName updated my answer!

Comment: @displayName does this answer help you?

Comment: `canActivateChild` guard is also run twice, so that doesn't solve the problem of extra API call

Comment: @displayName in dev environment change detection runs twice maybe that is why, when code is deployed it will run once, plz check that if it's correct